# Form redirect in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

So far in my app, I have an admin page and a project page. What I want for my admin page is a form, with a *select_tag*, that displays all existing projects. Upon submitting the form, it will direct the user to "projects/#", calling the selected projects "show" function.

```
<h1> Admin Page </h1>
<br/><br/>
 <%= form_tag( WHAT?, :method =>"put") do  %>
    <%= select_tag(:select_project, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id,:name), :size=>10) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Show Project") %>
<% end %>
```

I've been trying to figure out what to put in WHAT?. I'm also fairly certain I need to change a controller somewhere. Any input would be helpful

Thanks
SP

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for :project do |form| %>

   <%= form.select :id, Project.all.collect{|x|[x.name,x.id]} %><br/>
   <%= form.submit "Show Project"
<% end %>
```

And in your controller

```
unless params[:project].nil?
  @project = Project.find(params[:project][:id])
end
```

Comment: When I copied this in and hit Show Project, I get a routing error

    Routing Error: No route matches "/admin/index"

Thoughts?